# Audio FET Buffers and Negative Feedback

Tags: audio, feedback, jfet, negative, fet

I am struggling to come to term with how negative feedback helps *widen the scope* of input signals coming into FETs (or OpAmps for that matter, but I am using J201 JFETs).

I am aware that the largest input into a FET can be equal or less than the value of \$V_P\$ (\$V_{GSoff}\$) before clipping. I am also aware that \$V_S\$ acts as negative feedback allowing an initially larger signal to control the FET without clipping and (potentially) creating distortion.

Can somebody explain how this works and how I am able to ascertain what maths need to be used to work out what amplitude signal can be used on the input with a \$V_P\$ as a limit cleanly?

Image is just for an example. The values are not what I'm using.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the circuit given, if \$R_S = 0\$, then

$$v_{GS} = v_G - v_S = v_{IN} - 0 = v_{IN}$$

However, with a non-zero \$R_S\$, we have

$$v_{GS} = v_G - v_S = v_{IN} - i_S\cdot R_S < v_{IN}$$

Now, since

$$i_S = \beta(v_{GS} - V_P)^2 = \beta_0(1 + \lambda v_{DS})(v_{GS} - V_P)^2$$

we have

$$v_{GS} = v_{IN} - \beta R_S(v_{GS} - V_P)^2$$

> how I am able to ascertain what maths need to be used to work out what
>   amplitude signal can be used on the input with a VP as a limit

Solving for \$v_{IN}\$ yields

$$v_{IN} = \beta R_S(v_{GS})^2 + (1 - 2\beta R_SV_P)v_{GS} + \beta R_S(V_P)^2  $$

The bounds on \$v_{GS}\$ (for the \$i_S\$ equation to hold) are

$$V_P \le v_{GS} \le 0$$

so the bounds on \$v_{IN}\$ are

$$V_P \le v_{IN} \le \beta R_S (V_P)^2 $$

Thus, the input voltage range is extended by a factor of \$(1+\beta R_S |V_P|)\$

Answer (score 0):

In that circuit configuration, the source resistor allows V<sub>s</sub> to vary with V<sub>g</sub> which reduces the value of V<sub>gs</sub> across the device for a given V<sub>g</sub>. This also reduces the overall gain of the circuit, reducing the chances of output clipping as well.

Comment: This would be the same for a common drain config too correct?

Comment: Well, sort of. The common-drain configuration is also known as a "source follower". It has no voltage gain at all.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are interested primarily in the extended range for input signals (Quote: "*I am struggling to come to term with how negative feedback helps widen the scope of input signals coming into FETs*") the  answer is very simple:

The resistor Rs provides negative feedback.

This method has two distinct advantages: 
Stabilization of the dc operating point and stabilization of the gain value (against tolerances of FET parameters). More than that, the transfer function is linearized (reduced harmonic distortion)

However, the disadvantage is: Reduction in gain. Hence, for the same output voltage you need more input voltage (or with other words: More input voltage is allowed until signal clipping occurs; thus, the input voltage range is extended).

Comment: The thing getting me is this is how im seeing the VGS.

http://puu.sh/9qiOy/8231112e4c.png

If I have a input about 5v with only only 1v "worth of vp" how does the feedback increase the bandwidth

Comment: For an understanding how signal feedback influences the bandwidth you need a knowledge about the relations between (a) open-loop gain, (b) closed-loop gain and (c) loop gain - as well as the corresponding BODE diagrams. Are you familiar with these terms?

Comment: Im not yet sorry